# Areas of tetrahedron surfaces - how to calculate?

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis, surfaces

Reading up on Cauchy's stress theorem, I have stumbled over the so-called Cauchy tetrahedron, which is an important part of the theorem's proof. The following is cited straight from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Cauchy.E2.80.99s_stress_theorem.E2.80.94stress_tensor), but a similar argument (albeit shorter) is given in Aris' *Vectors, tensors, and the basic equations of fluid mechanics* p. 101:

> To prove this expression, consider a tetrahedron with three faces oriented in the
>   coordinate planes, and with an infinitesimal area $\mathrm{d}A$ oriented in an arbitrary
>   direction specified by a normal unit vector $n$. [...]
>   The area of the faces of the tetrahedron perpendicular to the axes can be found by
>   projecting $\mathrm{d}A$ into each face (using the dot product):
>   $$ \mathrm{d}A_i = (n\cdot e_i) \mathrm{d}A $$

**Can somebody give an explanation or better argument for this?** I fail to see how this seems to be (trivially) true.

Here is a figure illustrating this (also taken from Wikikpedia):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a two-dimensional shape of area $A$ with normal $n$. And imagine that you are looking directly at it (along $n$). You will observe it to have its true area $A$.

Now imagine you rotate the shape by an angle $\theta$ about some arbitrary axis so that it now points in the direction $n'$.  If you are still looking along $n$ then you will observe the shape to have an area $A\cos\theta=A n\cdot n'$.

If you agree with that then the result in question should become clear.